# PHP not printing result of MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am using PHP/MySql to display some results from a database.

**CODE**

```
$query = "select *  from users where (fname like '%".$searchTerm."%') OR (lname like '%".$searchTerm."%')";
$result = $db->query($query);

echo "yoooo";
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;

echo "<br/>".$num_rows." results st 2";
for ($i=0; $i<$num_rows ; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $fn = $row['fname'];
    $ln=$row['lname'];
    echo "<br/>".stripslahes($fn)." ".stripslashes($ln);
}
```

This shows:

```
yoooo
1 results st 2
```

But nothing more... Why? I am sure that the names I use in the associative array are the column names in the table...

Comment: have you echoed your query ?

Comment: do some basic debugging. what does `var_dump($row)` show? then go and upgrade your PHP to something that's slightly less stone-age and doesn't enforce magic_quotes.

Comment: i'd wager the function `stripslahes` does not exist. please add a `print_r($row, 1)` after row initialization (or a var_dump)

Comment: hmm .. $fn  = stripslashes($fn);
   $ln = stripslashes($ln);
   echo "<br/>".$fn." ".$ln;

Comment: For security & efficiency issues, you should better to learn about Prepared Statements. A good point to start http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to:

- turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
- echo the query + make sure `$searchTerm` is safe(avoid sql injections)
- `var_dump($row)`